# Error when trying to add service reference

Tags: c#, java, web-services, glassfish, service-reference

We have a `WebService` running in `glassfish` and a client written in `C#`

When trying to add a `service reference` in visual studio, I get the errormessage

`unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported Content-Types are: [text/xml]`

This just worked until a few days ago, I do not know of any changes in client and server that could cause that.

I already get the message in the glassfish console window when I call "Add service reference", select the adress `http://localhost:8888/Service/MyWebService?wsdl` and press the `Go` button.

The service reference does not work, I do not get a connection to the `WebService` afterwards.

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**

**What can I do about it?**

**How can I find out more about what is going wrong?**

Here is the full error message. Please note that I translated some parts to make it more readable, (the supported and unsupported), please excuse if this is not the correct english errormessage.

```
[#|2013-06-25T12:04:28.316+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter|_ThreadID=139;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8888(5);|Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported Content-Types are: [text/xml]
com.sun.xml.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported Content-Types are: [text/xml]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:322)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:156)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:312)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:344)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.invokeAsync(HttpAdapter.java:509)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:206)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
|#]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something inside the WebService has changed.

But I was able to generate the proxy by calling svcutil in the Visual Studio command line manually.

The warnings there gave me good hints to change the webservice so that I can add a service reference now again.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you sending to your service? Look at "unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"

Could be that server receives what it does not expect to receive? E.g. suddenly changed encoding.

P.S. I can't comment, so answering

Comment: At the moment I do not send any data to the service. This is just what the Visual Studio does to generate a service reference. Trying to do it myself with svcutil, but without success up to now.

Comment: are you using wsdl file to generate service? can you post it too? or provide a link to it?

Comment: right now I'm using the command line `svcutil http://localhost:8888/Service/MyWebService?wsdl` so, yes, I use wsdl. What should I look for?

Comment: Well, you should look into wsdl file contents. If you can rollback to previous working version of your service and app, you could compare contents of wsdl file versions.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you're client is making the call using Soap 1.2 protocol, whereas the server is (by default) configured to use the Soap 1.1 protocol.